# i tried to use Spring JPA libary to get count how many rows in my table but i faced this issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm a beginner in Spring Boot, and while trying to learn, I encountered an issue. Despite my efforts to resolve it, I couldn't find a satisfactory solution.

> *****************************
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
> *****************************
>
> Description:
>
> Field questionDAO in com.demo.QuizApp.service.QuestionService required a bean of type 'com.demo.QuizApp.dao.questionDAO' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.demo.QuizApp.dao.questionDAO' in your configuration.

Here it's my code.
QuestionContoller.java

```
package com.demo.QuizApp.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.demo.QuizApp.service.QuestionService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("questions")
public class QuestionContoller {

    @Autowired
    QuestionService questionService;

    @GetMapping("AllQuestions")
    public Long getAllQuestionAll() {
        return questionService.getAllQuestionAll();
    }
}
```

QuestionService.java

```
package com.demo.QuizApp.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.demo.QuizApp.dao.questionDAO;

@Service
public class QuestionService {

    @Autowired
    questionDAO questionDAO;

    public long getAllQuestionAll() {
        return questionDAO.count();
    }
}
```

Question.java

```
package com.demo.QuizApp.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "questionTitle")
    private String questionTitle;
    @Column(name = "rightAnswer")
    private String rightAnswer;
    @Column(name = "diffcultyLevel")
    private String diffcultyLevel;
    @Column(name = "option1")
    private String option1;
    @Column(name = "option2")
    private String option2;
    @Column(name = "option3")
    private String option3;
    @Column(name = "option4")
    private String option4;
    
    
}
```

QuestionDAO.java

```
package com.demo.QuizApp.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.demo.QuizApp.model.Question;

@Repository
public interface questionDAO  extends JpaRepository<Question, Integer>{

}
```

application.pro

```
spring.application.name=QuizApp
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/QuestionDB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>QuizApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>QuizApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.49</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I want to use default methods of JPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Spring Boot!

Try removing the `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` line from application.properties.

`DataSourceAutoConfiguration` is responsible for automatic set-up of  Spring-boot's database connection and you're accidentally disabling it.

Under the hood, there's also a `JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration` that sets up your repository beans (your `questionDAO`) but it only runs if a data source has been set up.